# Rendering html in Angular2 templates

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have component which gets a string value contains html code. But when I try to insert it in template html code are not interpolated.

Example:

```
@Component({
    selector: "any-selector",
    template: `<tooltip-view>{{tooltipText}}</tooltip-view>`,
    directives: [TooltipComponent]
})
export class SomeClass {
    private tooltipText = "Here is amazing link <a href='/whatever'>Link</a>"
}
```

Comment: @HarryNinh No. I need to catch this data through ng-content

Comment: Try this `<tooltip-view><div [outerHTML]="tooltipText"></div></tooltip-view>`

Comment: @yurzui it's perfect!